# how to access node global variable in Spookyjs?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I want to use node global variable in Spooky.js.so how I access a global variable into SpookyJS. please help me into this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **.bind()** functionality. Example:

```
var globalVar = "foo";    
var spooky = new Spooky({...}, function (err) { ... }.bind({globalVar: globalVar}));
```